# Bind9 can't resolve mbs.microsoft.com

Tags: bind, domain-name-system

Our Bind 9 on Ubuntu 10.04.4  (9.7.0.dfsg.P1-1ubuntu0.8) can't resolve mbs.microsoft.com. Other Nameservers seem to be able to resolve the Name.

This is what bind logged on debug 9:

```
query failed (SERVFAIL) for mbs.microsoft.com/IN/A at query.c:4628
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be many reasons for SERVFAIL; According to the source code this problem appears because "Something has gone wrong". My suggestions is to start with:

```
dig +trace mbs.microsoft.com
```

on a problematic Ubuntu, then compare results with other servers.
I would also inspect the named.conf file to ensure that there is no problems with i.e. forwarding, etc. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have used +trace before and I get the right answer from the auth nameservers of Microsoft. All other queries work just fine on our nameserver, it's just the query for mbs.microsoft.com that does not work.

Comment: Reading your answer I assume you have several servers with exactly the same configuration and possibly bind version, right?

Comment: yes, we have two Bind Servers, the other one has 9.7.0.dfsg.P1-1ubuntu0.7 installed and does also not resolve  mbs.microsoft.com.

Comment: with "Other Nameservers seem to be able to resolve the Name" i meant e.g the nameserver 8.8.8.8 (google)